# Why doesn't this conversion work in Powershell like in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, types

I am trying to convert a calculated value to uint16. I've hard coded for the sake of the example.  In C# it works. But, what I believe is the same code in Powershell fails. Consider the following:

In the powershell code example it produces:

```
Cannot convert value "101398986" to type "System.UInt16". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16."
At D:\OneDrive\Desktop\VaribleCasting2.ps1:2 char:1
+ [uint16]$v = [uint16]$g
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible
```

I've tried [convert]::ToUInt16($g) it produces:

```
Exception calling "ToUInt16" with "1" argument(s): "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16."
At D:\OneDrive\Desktop\VaribleCasting2.ps1:2 char:1
+ [uint16]$v = [convert]::ToUInt16($g)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OverflowException
```

PowerShell(fails):

```
$g = 101398986
[uint16]$v = [uint16]$g
$v
```

C#(succeeds):

```
using System;

namespace NumericTypeTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var g = 101398986;
            UInt16 v = (UInt16)g;
            Console.WriteLine(v);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation was that .NET in both platforms would produce the same result. Thanks for any help!

Comment: i don't think you are getting a real UInt16 in c#. take a look at this >>> `[uint16]::MaxValue` <<< note that the max value is 64k ... which is _exactly_ what one would expect. your number is 101k+ ... [*grin*]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint16.maxvalue

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the limits.  What I am asking is why does this work in C# .NET but not PowerShell .NET.  Clearly there is something going on here I don't understand.  This is clearly not the same cast.

Comment: take a look at the actual result in c# - i will bet you that the number is either _truncated_ or coerced into a larger `[int]` type. [*grin*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Powershell does checked arithmetic by default (like Visual Basic), unlike C#. This means you do get [OverflowException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception) by default when you overflow, instead of the runtime silently truncating the result.

You might want to look at [How to suppress overflow-checking in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720138/how-to-suppress-overflow-checking-in-powershell) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give your 16 bits integer the number `101398986`, that's totally impossible as long a your are using 16 bits, cause a 16 bit integer need to be under or equal 65,535

Or if its signed integer : -32,767 < number < 32,767

So better to use an 32 bits integer for your case:

```
var g = 101398986;
UInt32 v = (UInt32)g;
```

Where your number must be under or equal 4294967295 (for 32 bits integer)